Dell Latitude 5401 stuck at 800MHz
My Dell Latitude 5401 has an annoying habit of getting stuck at 800 MHZ (the max is 4.2GHz) once it's got warm.
Under load it will run near max frequency for a while, with increasing fan speed as expected, until core temps go over 96 degC, then it drops to 800MHz on all cores - and stays there even after temperatures drop right down, and even if it's heavily loaded.  Whatever it was doing just crawls along until a reboot.
I'm happy with it throttling frequency to cool down, but once temperatures have dropped it should surely allow speed to rise again?
I have cleaned out the fan ducts with compressed air, and removed and replaced the thermal paste but that has made no difference.  Any other ideas either for a fix or for further troubleshooting steps would be most welcome.
Ubuntu 20.04, Dell Latitude 5401, Intel i5-9400H, using stress -c 8 -m 8 to test, and cpufreq-info and sensors to monitor results.

96°C is quite hot for an IC, almost to water's boiling point! Check the cooling settings, which should have throttled back CPU and increased fan speed long before it got that hot. Perhaps there is now damage, causing that latching effect until reboot.
